# Find analytical expression of the join probability distribution of Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $x$ be a variable that is independently sampled from a Gaussian random variable $F_x = {N}(m_x, \sigma^2_x)$

Let $y$ be a variable whose value is $y = f(x)$, and $f$ is some continuous function, then $y$ is generated according to a probability density function $F_Y$.

Find the analytical expression for the joint probability density function $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

Is this problem well-posed?

If so, how to go about finding $F_{X,Y}$?

Comment: It's well known that the Lebesgue measure of the graph of a measurable function is zero.

Answer (score -1):

The joint density function is well-defined:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)=f_X(x)\delta(y-f(x))$$
where $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Dirac delta function.

Comment: Thank you. How did you derive that the conditional density $f_{Y|X}$ is $\delta(y - f(x))$?

Comment: Because $x$ is already known, $y$ is actually a constant $f(x)$, which takes the degenerate probability density in the form of the Dirac delta function.  See [Density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_scalar).

Comment: The joint density is not well-defined...

Comment: I know Dirac delta is not really a function but a linear functional. I call it well-defined because most non-mathematicians simply view it as a generalized density function.